# delegate HTTP request to Jersey

Tags: jersey-2.0

I have a nano HTTP based web server, that is supposed to delegate its calls to a jersey 2.22.2. On the webserver class constructor I declare an ApplicationHandler as a instance variable:

```
    ApplicationHandler newHandler;
```

Then in the constructor I initilize it and register a Sample resource class:

```
    Object[] instances = new Object[1];
    instances[0] = new SampleResource();

    ResourceConfig app = new ResourceConfig();
    app.registerInstances(instances);
    newHandler = new ApplicationHandler(app);
```

On the method that processes Http requests I create a ContainerRequest and execute the apply method on the application handler :

```
                SecurityContext secContext = new SecurityContext() {
                @Override
                public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                    return new Principal() {
                        @Override
                        public String getName() {
                            return "user";
                        }
                    };
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isUserInRole(String s) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean isSecure() {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
                    return null;
                }
            };
            PropertiesDelegate propertiesDelegate = new PropertiesDelegate() {

                Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
                @Override
                public Object getProperty(String s) {
                    return props.get(s);
                }

                @Override
                public Collection<String> getPropertyNames() {
                    return props.keySet();
                }

                @Override
                public void setProperty(String s, Object o) {
                    props.put(s, o);
                }

                @Override
                public void removeProperty(String s) {
                    props.remove(s);
                }
            };
            ContainerRequest request = new ContainerRequest(new URI("http://localhost:2000"), new URI("/test"), session.getMethod().toString(), secContext, propertiesDelegate);
            Future<ContainerResponse> responseFuture = newHandler.apply(request);
            ContainerResponse response = responseFuture.get();
            Object entity = response.getEntity();
```

Below is the code for the SampleResource class :

```
public class SampleResource {

@GET
@Path("test")
public Response testMethod() {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
}
```

}

The main reason for doing this is that I want to call a custom API that injects objects into the annotated resource classes. 
Stepping through the code, all I get is a NotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inject custom Objects to the resources class you can do that in two waus

1. using @Context -- By adding your custom object to application context
2. usign @Inject  -- By binding the application to resource config

to use @Context , you need to extend the java.security.Principal object and declare your object fields, and you can instantiate and assign values by using security context.

to user @InJect , you need to register org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder like below

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
public MyApplication() {
    packages("org.foo.rest;org.bar.rest");
   register(new AbstractBinder() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bindFactory(ObjectThatneedtoInject.class).to(yourClass.class);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: although your answer is correct, I am not using it that way. I have my own object instances injected through my own annotations. What I want is to pass an HTTP request for a given path to Jersey, so that it can call my objects.